# XCTest hangs indefinitely partway through running tests

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

When I run my complete tests: (command u), partway through, they hang. I'm not aware of any infinite loops or any other way this would be triggered.

While it appears to hang on `testMatrixToCsv()`, when I comment out the body of this method, it still hangs.

When I ran each completed test individually, none of them caused a hang to occur.  Two of the tests took slightly longer than the others.  I commented out the bodies of those two tests, and I still encounter the infinite hang.

I am modifying a local csv, and reading it immediately after.  I haven’t modified the boiler setup nor tear down code.  There are no shared variables between tests that have internal nor public setter methods.

How can I begin to find the source of this hang?

Comment: Could you formulate an actual question please and perhaps add something more useful than screenshots of menus?  Are you accessing any resources like files? Anything special going on in the setup/tearDown methods of your tests? Do you have any variables that are shared between tests?

Comment: @joakim thank you  for the feedback.  Is that better?

Comment: Yes it’s definitely better but unfortunately I can’t think of anything that might cause this right now

Comment: You're in good company @JoakimDanielson, I'm stumped too.  I'm at the start over from the most recent working commit at this point.